# Parallelizing a for loop with map and reduce in spark with pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

In my application, I am creating different data-frames from data in different locations on S3, and then trying to merge the dataframes into a single dataframes. Right now I am using a for loop for this. But I have a feeling this can be done in a much more efficient way using map and reduce functions in pyspark. Here's my code:

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext, GroupedData
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime


sparkConf = SparkConf().setAppName('myTestApp')
sc = SparkContext(conf=sparkConf)
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

filepath = 's3n://my-s3-bucket/report_date='

date_from = pd.to_datetime('2016-08-01',format='%Y-%m-%d')
date_to = pd.to_datetime('2016-08-22',format='%Y-%m-%d')
datelist = pd.date_range(date_from, date_to)

First = True

#THIS is the for-loop I want to get rid of
for dt in datelist:
    date_string = datetime.strftime(dt, '%Y-%m-%d')
    print('Running the pyspark - Data read for the date - '+date_string)
    df = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").options(header = "false", inferschema = "true", delimiter = "\t").load(filepath + date_string + '/*.gz')

    if First:
        First=False
        df_Full = df
    else:
        df_Full = df_Full.unionAll(df)
```

Comment: Do you have a constraint to use Spark? If not have you considered using dask instead? dask is designed among other nice things to achieve what you are trying to do easily

Comment: I need to use spark because after this I will be running Spark algos in it. And the size of data is also quite large.

Comment: http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/spark.html

Answer (score 3):

Actually iterative `union`, although suboptimal, is not the biggest issue here. Much more serious problem is introduced by schema inference (`inferschema = "true"`).

It not only makes data frame creation not lazy but also requires a separate data scan just for inference. If you know schema up front you should provide it as an argument for `DataFrameReader`:

```
schema = ...

df = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").schema(schema)
```

otherwise you can extract it from the first `DataFrame`. Combined with well tuned parallelism it should work just fine but if number of files you fetch is large you should also consider a little bit smarter approach than an iterative union. You'll find an example in my answer to [Spark union of multiple RDDs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33743978/1560062). It is more expensive but has better general properties.

Regarding your idea it is not possible to nest operations on distributed data structures so if you want to read data inside `map` you'll have to use S3 client directly without utilizing `SQLContext`.