# PySpark: Union of all the dataframes in a Python dictionary

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

I have a dictionary `my_dict_of_df` which consists of **variable** number of dataframes each time my program runs. I want to create a new dataframe that is a union of all these dataframes.

My dataframes look like-

```
my_dict_of_df["df_1"], my_dict_of_df["df_2"] and so on...
```

How do I union all these dataframes?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spark union of multiple RDDs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33743978/spark-union-of-multiple-rdds)

Comment: @pault I've consulted that answer, but the return value is a list of dataframe objects and not a new unionized dataframe. I intend to do further operations on this newly created dataframe.

Comment: The return value on the linked post and the code in my other comment is a DataFrame. It is not a list of DataFrames.

Comment: It's because of the way `unionAll` is defined here to take in `*dfs`. Either call it by unpacking your values: `unionAll(*my_dic.values())` OR change the function definition to take a single (iterable) argument: `def unionAll(dfs): return reduce(DataFrame.unionAll, dfs)`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Consulted the solution given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33743978/spark-union-of-multiple-rdds), thanks to [@pault](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5858851/pault).

```
from functools import reduce
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame

def union_all(*dfs):
    return reduce(DataFrame.union, dfs)

df1 = sqlContext.createDataFrame([(1, "foo1"), (2, "bar1")], ("k", "v"))
df2 = sqlContext.createDataFrame([(3, "foo2"), (4, "bar2")], ("k", "v"))
df3 = sqlContext.createDataFrame([(5, "foo3"), (6, "bar3")], ("k", "v"))

my_dic = {}
my_dic["df1"] = df1
my_dic["df2"] = df2
my_dic["df3"] = df3

new_df = union_all(*my_dic.values())

print(type(new_df))   # <class 'pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame'>
print(new_df.show())  

"""
+---+----+
|  k|   v|
+---+----+
|  1|foo1|
|  2|bar1|
|  3|foo2|
|  4|bar2|
|  5|foo3|
|  6|bar3|
+---+----+
"""
```

**Edit**: using `DataFrame.union` instead of `DataFrame.unionAll` since the latter is deprecated.

Comment: I'd suggest using DataFrame.unionByName if you are unsure your columns are in the same order