# Mount external and partitioned delta table in Databricks

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, delta-lake

I have an external delta table partitioned by year in my storage, so when I try to "mount" the delta in Databricks table using this code:

```
CREATE TABLE if not exists profitek.products
                   USING DELTA                 
                   LOCATION 'dbfs:/mnt/curated-l1/profitek/products'
```

I get this error:

You are trying to create an external table `spark_catalog`.`general`.`products`
from `dbfs:/mnt/curated-l1/general/products` using Databricks Delta, but there is no transaction log present at
`dbfs:/mnt/curated-l1/general/products/_delta_log`. Check the upstream job to make sure that it is writing using
format("delta") and that the path is the root of the table.

The _delta_log file is inside every partition

```
products
│
├── 2022-01-01
│   ├── _delta_log
│   ├── part_01.parquet
│   └── part_02.parquet
├── 2022-01-02
    ├── _delta_log
    ├── part_01.parquet
    └── part_02.parquet
```

So I can mount a PART of the table using something like this

```
CREATE TABLE if not exists profitek.products
                   USING DELTA                 
                   LOCATION 'dbfs:/mnt/curated-l1/profitek/products/2022-01-01'
```

How can I "mount" the full table, with all his partitions??

Comment: hi @vAndrés Bustamante, my questions is, are you want to mount 2022-01-01 and 2022-01-02 location at time ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your delta table is **not** partitioned using delta's partitioning capabilities: `df.write.format("delta").partitionBy(<date_column_name>).save(path)`

If done in the way described above, the directory structure would look like this:

```
products
├── _delta_log
│   └── 0000000.json
├── 2022-01-01
│   ├── part_01.parquet
│   └── part_02.parquet
├── 2022-01-02
    ├── part_01.parquet
    └── part_02.parquet
```

As per the directory structure provided by you, it seems the delta tables were partitioned *explicitly*, i.e.: the partitions were explicitly written to those locations. Something like:

- `df_2022_01_01.write.format("delta").save("products/2022-01-01")`
- `df_2022_01_02.write.format("delta").save("products/2022-01-02")`

To get all the partitions in one df, you need to read individual ones and simply union them (assuming schema is same):

```
df_2022_01_01 = spark.read.format("delta").load("products/2022-01-01")
df_2022_01_02 = spark.read.format("delta").load("products/2022-01-02")
//then union the two dfs
df = df_2022_01_01.union(df_2022_01_02)
```

I've shown for 2 dfs only, you can use [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56363561/pyspark-how-to-append-dataframes-in-for-loop) to union dataframes in a for-loop.

Now that you have complete data in the df, you can partition it using delta for easier access later on:
`df.write.format("delta").partitionBy(<date_column_name>).save("/products/complete-delta")`